# Opacity transition on page load does not kicks in on load

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions, opacity

I want to have a very simple loading effect with a quick opacity change on the whole body. So I use the following CSS

```
body {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}

body.show-page {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

and add `.show-page` on load. Here is the live code http://plnkr.co/edit/Ze5TiqkZYiM41VJZVDuB?p=preview

For some reason it does not transition. After the page is loaded the transition works if I add/remove this class, but when loading, it does not happen. Any idea why?

Comment: which browser are you using? you may need vendor prefixes

Comment: I think you need to style zero opacity in the body tag `<body style="opacity: 0;">`. then it will be applied from start loading but not after css load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script will run before body has finished loading as the script is inside the body tag.

You maybe want something like this:

```
function fadeIn() {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    body.className += 'show-page';
}
window.onload = fadeIn;
```

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YZEBgIi128EM5U1g5zF3?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

One workaround can be to slightly delay (50ms) your JS doing so:

```
   setTimeout(function(){body.className += 'show-page';}, 50);
```